# Let $R$ be a ring with unit $1$ and $\phi: \mathbb Z \implies D$ be defined as $\phi(n) = n1$. Show this is an homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm wondering what does it mean to multiply $n\in \mathbb Z$ by a member of $R$? Shouldn't $\mathbb Z$ be a subring of $R$ in order for me to do it? What is this exercise really doing?

I'm supposed to prove that $\phi(n+k) = (n+k)1$? What does it mean?

Then the exercise asks me to prove that $\{m \in \mathbb Z: m1 = 0 \in R\}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z$

I can't understand

Comment: $nx=x+\dots +x$, $n$-times.

Comment: To take a concrete example  - quite aside from doing the question - but to help you understand: do you know that $\mathbb Z/ 10 \mathbb Z$ is a ring?

Comment: cont - if you understand that  $R=\mathbb Z/ 10 \mathbb Z$ is a ring: does  $n\cdot x$ makes sense to you in this $R$, for $n, x \in R$? Do you see (if $n\ge 0$) that $n \cdot 1 = 1 + \cdots +1$, $n$ times, as @PaxKivimae writes, in this $R$?